# Android Resize nested horizontal recyclerview inside of scrollview, when user scrolls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-animation, carousel

I have an horizontal carousel that is embedded in a vertical scrollview.

I want to resize the content of the carousel once the user scrolls, so that the content will be collapsed when the user scrolls, and expanded when the user returns to the top (similar to what happens on material toolbar)

I know how to resize the carousel, but I'm not sure on how to notify the carousel views the new height, so that they can adapt their content to the new height.

Is there an standard way to do this?

My first thoughts are:

1) Make the carousel's height static, and change it on scroll. Then have the views implement `onLayoutChangeListener` or `onSizeChange` to make the change.

2) Make the carousel's height wrap_content (as it is now), and send the scroll event directly to the carousel views so that they change their own height (I'm not sure on how to do this)